# Expectation of a random variable that is similar to standard deviation distribution

Tags: probability

Let's assume $\xi_i \sim N(0,\epsilon), i = 1,\dots, 9$ and $\xi_i$ are independent. How to compute next expectation?
$$
E\sqrt{\frac{(\xi_1 - \frac{\xi_1 + \xi_2 + \xi_3}{3})^2 + (\xi_4 - \frac{\xi_4 + \xi_5 + \xi_6}{3})^2 + (\xi_7 - \frac{\xi_7 + \xi_8 + \xi_9}{3})^2}{3}}
$$

P.S. A link to [standard deviation distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each random variable similar to $$\xi_1 - \frac{\xi_1 + \xi_2 + \xi_3}{3}$$ is normal centered with variance $\frac23\epsilon$ and they are independent hence the expectation to be computed is $\frac13\sqrt{2\epsilon}E(Z)$ with $$Z=\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2},$$ where $(X_k)$ is i.i.d. standard normal. Now, the distribution of $Z$ is well known...

Comment: Ah, I did not know about Chi distribution. Thanks!

Comment: Should it be "...with variance $\frac{4}{3}\epsilon$" or indeed $\frac{2}{3}\epsilon$?

Comment: @Stef $\left(\frac23\right)^2+\left(\frac13\right)^2+\left(\frac13\right)^2=\frac23$.

Comment: Ok, sorry I din not see that $ξ_1$ appeared twice. +1